# NSURLConnection with synchrounous call not returning values sometime?

Tags: iphone

I am calling one URL which returns JSON string as response. I have used NSURLConnection with synchronous call but my problem is i can able to get the result the sometimes and sometimes i am getting nil value as response. Can anyone tell me where i did mistake in the below code.

Code which i have used to call url is below,

```
NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:request];
NSURLRequest *urlReq=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlString];
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
NSError *errorVal=nil;

NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlReq returningResponse:&response error:&errorVal];
```

Please anyone help me where i did mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the error object when you see the nil return value? It may tell you (or us) what is going on